# Adding a label to a path with D3

Tags: d3.js

I am building a graph with D3 and represent the links between nodes as paths. I want to add a label for each path by using the following code:

```
path_labels = path_labels.data(links);
path_labels.enter().append("text")
                    .attr("class", "linklabel")
                    .style("font-size", "12px")
                    .attr("text-anchor", "start")
                    .append("textPath")
                    .attr("xlink:href", function (d) {
                        return "#linkId_0";
                    })
                    .text(function (d) {
                        return "my text"; 
                    });
```

When I look at the result, text is appended, but not the textPath inside the text element.

Can someone help?

The full code can be found at http://jsfiddle.net/3u0oage7/

Comment: Are the elements appended correctly? What exactly happens?

Comment: The textPath is not appended inside the text element. The code seams to "stop" after .attr("text-anchor", "start").

Comment: Do you get any error messages?

Comment: No errors, please take a look at the jsfiddle link for the full example.

Comment: So what should I do in the jsfiddle to trigger the bug?

Comment: When you create at least 2 nodes and then draw a line from one to another, you should get a new path with a label on it. The path is created, but the label is not shown.

Comment: That's not running that code though, is it?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to the problem. The code I posted works as supposed. The problem was that in my code I had this:

```
svg.selectAll('text').
                    text(function (d) {
                        return d.label;
                    });
```

This code was changing all the text elements. I changed the selector so it selects only the text elements corresponding to a circle.